# Google sheets formula for grouping rows?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a dataset of portfolio mutations from investing and would like to split the data into two sets: 'sold assets' and 'open positions'. Below is an example dataset with the desired outcome.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrwPk.png) &
[Sample in google sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fqaiTJd_2EO0rZCqSFtOx_kLFNxfSZzBNF450zPxTiA/edit?usp=sharing).

##### The portfolio mutations sample data:

| Ticker | Action | Purchase Date | Purchase Price | Shares | Selling Date | Selling Price | Shares |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAPL | Buy | 1/30/2023 | $143.00 | 100 |  |  |  |
| AAPL | Buy | 3/14/2023 | $152.00 | 100 |  |  |  |
| AMZN | Buy | 5/4/2023 | $104.00 | 50 |  |  |  |
| AAPL | Sell |  |  |  | 7/11/2023 | $187.00 | 200 |
| WMT | Buy | 8/22/2023 | $52.30 | 300 |  |  |  |
| AMZN | Buy | 9/28/2023 | $124.00 | 20 |  |  |  |
| AAPL | Buy | 10/25/2023 | $172.00 | 80 |  |  |  |
| PG | Buy | 12/11/2023 | $145.00 | 430 |  |  |  |
| WMT | Sell |  |  |  | 2/28/2024 | $59.50 | 100 |
| PG | Sell |  |  |  | 3/8/2024 | $160.00 | 430 |

What happens is that one can open a position (AAPL) and close it later that year. Further down one's investment career, AAPL may be purchased again. The closed position should be displayed in the 'Sold Assets' list. At the same time, the new position is displayed in the 'Open Positions' list.
[Color-coded position groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8p7DE.png)

##### The desired outcome for 'sold assets' is as follows:

| Ticker | Last Sell Date | Profit/Loss |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAPL | 7/11/2023 | $7,900.00 |
| WMT | 2/28/2024 | $720.00 |
| PG | 3/8/0202 | $6,450.00 |

##### The desired outcome for 'open positions' is as follows:

| Ticker | First Buy Date | Unrealised Profit/loss |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AMZN | 5/4/2023 | $4,790.50 |
| AAPL | 10/25/2023 | $533.60 |
| WMT | 8/22/2023 | $1,790.00 |

I tried various ways and added my attempt on a separate sheet [here in the google sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fqaiTJd_2EO0rZCqSFtOx_kLFNxfSZzBNF450zPxTiA/edit?usp=sharing). I sum the shares from every unique ticker and compare to '=0' for Sold Assets and '>0' for 'Open Positions'. This works well when a ticker is not repeatedly bought and sold like AAPL in this example.

I was thinking of resolving this issue by somehow grouping the colored rows together and retrieving the necessary data to display in the 2 lists.

Is there a formula/query to create the desired outcome? And is it possible without script?

I thank you in advance!

Comment: Please do NOT provide sample data and expected outcomes in an image. Would you please edit the question to include this information in the body of the question.

Comment: I am sorry for only providing the data in images and Google Sheets. By adding the data tables, I hope that the question is now according to the guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

*Here's one approach you may test out for the **`Sold Assets`** part:*

```js
=let(Σ,filter({A5:A,G5:I},G5:G),tick,unique(index(Σ,,1)), date,index(xlookup(tick,index(Σ,,1),index(Σ,,2),,,-1)), pl_,map(tick,lambda(Δ,
 let(Ξ,sum(filter(index(Σ,,4),index(Σ,,1)=Δ)), Γ,sum(filter(index(Σ,,3)*index(Σ,,4),index(Σ,,1)=Δ)), Λ,filter({A5:A,D5:D,E5:E},A5:A=Δ,E5:E),
 Γ-sum(map({0;scan(,index(Λ,,3),lambda(a,c,a+c))},vstack(index(Λ,,3),),vstack(index(Λ,,2),),lambda(x,y,z,ifs(x+y<=Ξ,y,isbetween(Ξ,x,x+y),Ξ-x,1,)*z)))))),
 hstack(tick,date,pl_))
```

[image]